# Access form elements

Tags: c#

I'm creating a multiform application in c#. I'm storing the values from the user in a List in form 1 and I want to access the same stored values of the same list in form 2...I m not able to access the stored values...The error I'm getting indicates that there are no values in the list which I'm accessing from form 2...Please help me out...

```
public Form1() 
{ 
    InitializeComponent(); 
} 

public List<string> sub = new List<string>(); 
public int clickcounter = 1; 

public void additems() 
{ 
    sub.Add("Java"); 
    sub.Add("Web Technology"); 
    sub.Add("Software Engineering"); 
    sub.Add("Networks"); 
    sub.Add("ADO.net"); 
}

public void show() 
{ 
    int x = 10; 
    int y = 10; 
    int m = sub.Count; 

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
    { 
        string name = "txtBox_" + (i + 1).ToString("00"); 
        TextBox txt = new TextBox(); 
        txt.Name = name; 
        this.Controls.Add(txt); 
        txt.Text = sub[i]; 
        txt.ReadOnly = true; 
        y += 20; 
        txt.Location = new Point(x, y); 
        txt.Width = 120; 
    } 
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (clickcounter == 1) 
    { 
        additems(); 
        show(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public List<string> sub = new List<string>();
        public int clickcounter = 1;
        public void additems()
        {
            sub.Add("Java");
            sub.Add("Web Technology");
            sub.Add("Software Engineering");
            sub.Add("Networks");
            sub.Add("ADO.net");
        }

Comment: public void show()
        {
            int x = 10;
            int y = 10;
            int m = sub.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                string name = "txtBox_" + (i + 1).ToString("00");
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.Name = name;
                this.Controls.Add(txt);
                txt.Text = sub[i];
                txt.ReadOnly = true;
                y += 20;
                txt.Location = new Point(x, y);
                txt.Width = 120;

            }

        }

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (clickcounter == 1)
            {
                additems();
                show();
            }

Comment: clickcounter++;
            sub.Add(textBox1.Text);
            int n = sub.Count;
            int x = 10;
            int y = 10;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                string name = "txtBox_" + (i + 1).ToString("00");
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.Name = name;
                this.Controls.Add(txt);
                txt.Width = 120;
                txt.Text = sub[i];
          y += 20;
                txt.Location = new Point(x, y);
                txt.ReadOnly = true;
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }

Comment: I'm trying to access the values stored in 'sub' using form 2

Comment: what error do you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't access the Object stored in Form1 from Form2, but pass the Object as a property to Form2.

e.G:
Defining the Property:

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public List<String> PersonNames { get; set; }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Passing the object from form1 to form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      List<String> PersonNames = new List<String>() { "Harald", "Thomas", "Markus" };
      ObjektBinaerSerialisieren form2 = new ObjektBinaerSerialisieren();
      form2.PersonNames = PersonNames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a local *List* variable for your Form2, and a constructor, something like

```
Public List<String> locaList;
public form2( List aList )
{
   InitializeComponent( );
   localList = aList;
}
```

then just pass your *List* when you create your form 2.

Hope that helps.